# NPM got stuck in terminal while creating react app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules, create-react-app

I was creating my first react app and I did everything as guided by react [Getting Started](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/) page.
When I run **npx create-react-app first-app** or **npm init react-app first-app** the installing stuff started which took a couple of minutes.Two bars of loading got finished and then the terminal got stuck with a *blinking cursor* at this point as shown in the image down below.
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfRf8.png)
I waited for around *1 hr* before aborting the process.Also when i took a look at the **exam-portal** folder there was only **node_modules**,**pakage.json** and **pakage-lock.json** files.*No src or public folder*.
**~Any help will be appreciated~**
*'Thanks in advance'*

Answer (score 2):

Follow below steps

```
update node (and npm) to latest version, if not latest

npm cache clean --force 
npx create-react-app first-app
```